# Keep menu open after selecting a item

Tags: qooxdoo

I need my menu (opened by a menubutton) to stay open after you select an item from the menu. So that you can select more then one items before it closes (by clicking outside of the list)

I couldn't find anything in the api, so i hope you guys know the trick

Another solution would be if you hover over the button, then the menu opens. When you leave the menu with your mouse, the menu would close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross post from the mailing List:
http://qooxdoo.678.n2.nabble.com/Keeping-a-menu-open-after-selecting-an-option-td7580767.html;cid=1345706918184-716

Answer from the list:

In order to keep the menu open after clicks, you need to provide your 
own implementation of menu.Button. You can subclass qx.ui.menu.Button, 
and then need to overwrite the _onClick method so it doens't call 
qx.ui.menu.Manager.hideAll (Have a look on qx.ui.menu.Button source code).

Then, onMouseout of the entire menu, call 
qx.ui.menu.Manager.getInstance().hideAll().